# What exactly are the stages of the reaction between an oxygen ion and a water molecule?

Tags: physical-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, kinetics, atmospheric-chemistry

I found information on the website [water.lsbu.ac.uk - Oxygen and water](https://water.lsbu.ac.uk/water/o2water.html):

> Between altitudes of $80-\pu{100 km}$, $\ce{O2^{\small{\bullet}+}}$ and $\ce{NO+}$ ions are the dominant cationic species. $\ce{O2^{\small{\bullet}+}}$ ions react with water molecules to form  $\ce{H2O.O2^{\small{\bullet}+}}$   species (see figure left) [4020].. At lower altitudes, this further reacts with more water molecules to form hydrogen ions.

that as a result of the reaction of an oxygen ion with water, a hydronium ion can be obtained. If I understand correctly, the oxygen ion in interaction with water dissociates the water molecule, but how does the formation of the hydronium ion occur?

I hope that there is someone here who would be able to write down the stages of the reaction for me. Thank you.

Comment: For plain text formatting by StackExchange markdown, see as inspiration [SE meta - formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) // [SE meta -  tables](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support)  // [Advanced formatting](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3044/hidden-points-of-editing-you-probably-didnt-know)

Comment: Chem+Math Expression formatting reference:
 [MathJax Basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) / [Chem+Math expressions/formulas/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here) / [Upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) / [Math SE Mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
// MathJax is preferred not to be used in CH SE Q titles.